# How does ridge regression reduce the variance of the estimates of $\beta$

Tags: regression, ridge-regression

In the scikit-learn library, Ridge class, there is a note that reads: "Regularization improves the conditioning of the problem and reduces the variance of the estimates."

Given the expression of beta for ridge regression:

$\beta = (X^T X + \lambda I_d)^{-1} X^T y$

How does the addition of $\lambda I_d$ to the moments matrix improve the condition number of the inverse? And how exactly does it reduce the variance of the estimates (mathematically)?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151304, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118712, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69205.

Answer (score 2):

The additional term $\lambda I_d$ can be interpreted as adding some bias and it is the bias that reduces the variance.

1. The addition of $\lambda I_d$ is equivalent to adding a penalty term to the least squares optimization problem $$\min_{\beta}: \overbrace{ (y-X\beta )^T(y-X\beta ) }^{\text{least squares}}+ \overbrace{\lambda (\beta^T\beta)}^{\text{additional penalty}}$$
2. The penalty term is equivalent to constraining the parameters to a particular maximum size.

   $$\min_{\beta}: { (y-X\beta )^T(y-X\beta ) } \qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta^T\beta < c$$
3. Constraining the
   parameters will reduce the variance of the parameters.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that the variance of the biased estimates is lower than that of the OLS? Can we quantify the bias/variance tradeoff?

Comment: @Paca possibly you might do this with an eigendecomposition. You can rewrite $$X^TX = Q\Lambda Q^T$$ where $Q$ is a matrix with eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ a matrix with eigenvalues on the diagonal. Then $$X^TX + \lambda I= Q\Lambda^\dagger Q^T$$ where $\Lambda^\dagger = \Lambda + \lambda I$ and for the inverse you get $$(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} = Q(\Lambda^\dagger)^{-1} Q^T$$ and so it is easy to see how the inverse changes due to the additional $\lambda I$ term. The terms on the diagonal matrix $(\Lambda^\dagger)^{-1}$ are smaller...

Comment: ...I imagine that you can use that fact to show that the variance of the expression $$(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} X^TY = Q (\Lambda^\dagger)^{-1} Q^TX^TY$$ is smaller.

Comment: But a smaller variance is not always better. It may be more difficult to show that it also means a smaller error (which is variance + bias).

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rid}{\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}_\text{ridge}}\DeclareMathOperator{\ols}{\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}}\DeclareMathOperator{\bias}{\hat{\boldsymbol\beta^\ast}} \DeclareMathOperator{\tr} {trace}\DeclareMathOperator{\xx}{\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf X}$

Condition number (cf. $\rm [I],$ chapter $4,$ p. $189$) $\kappa:\mathcal M\to \mathbb R^{\geq 0}$ is defined as

$$\kappa(\mathbf A) := \Vert \mathbf A \Vert \left\Vert \mathbf A^{-1}\right\Vert,\tag 1$$ where $\Vert \mathbf A\Vert := \displaystyle\max_{\Vert \mathbf x\Vert = 1} \Vert\mathbf{Ax} \Vert.$ Corresponding to $\Vert \mathbf x\Vert^2 =\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2, $ the matrix norm subordinate to it can be shown (cf.$\rm [II],$ chapter $1,$ p. $60$) to be $\Vert \mathbf A \Vert= \sqrt{\lambda_1}, $ the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf A^\mathsf T\mathbf A; $ if $\bf A$ is symmteric, then $$ \kappa(\mathbf A) =\frac{\lambda_\max(\mathbf A) }{\lambda_\min(\mathbf A)},\tag{1.I}$$

Eigenvalues of $\xx+ k\mathbf I$ are of the form $\lambda_i+ k, ~\lambda_i$ being an eigenvalue of $\xx;$ then from $\rm(1.I), $ $$\kappa(\mathbf A) =\frac{\lambda_\max + k }{\lambda_\min + k}.\tag 2$$ Since $k> 0,$ one is able to circumvent the scenario of dividing the numerator by a very small number $\lambda_\min, $ i.e. at least there would be $k:$ this would be alleviating from what would have been a very large condition number.

The problem with $\ols$ is that, albeit being unbiased, the variance is large and the point estimate is unstable. One tradeoff could be that of allowing biased estimators, say $\bias,$ in that, as echoed in Sextus Empiricus' [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/589198/362671), the variance of $\bias$ can be lowered such that the mean square error of $\bias$ is smaller than the variance of $\ols$ (cf.$\rm[III]$, chapter $9,$ p. $305$).

If $L_1^2:= \left(\ols-\boldsymbol\beta\right) ^\mathsf T\left(\ols-\boldsymbol\beta\right), $ then since $\mathbb E[\boldsymbol\varepsilon ]=\mathbf 0,~\mathbb E\left[\boldsymbol\varepsilon\boldsymbol\varepsilon^\mathsf T\right]=\sigma^2\mathbf I, $ \begin{align}\mathbb E\left[ L^2_1\right]&= \sigma^2\tr\left(\xx\right)^{-1}\\&= \sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^p\frac1{\lambda_i},\tag 3\end{align} $\lambda_i$ being the eigenvalues of $\xx.$

Now, $$\rid= \underbrace{\left[\xx + k\mathbf I\right]^{-1}}_{:=\mathbf W}\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf y; \tag{4.I}$$ equivalently $$\rid =\underbrace{\left[\mathbf I +k\left(\xx\right)^{-1}\right]^{-1}}_{:=\mathbf Z}\ols.\tag{4.II}$$ As $\mathbf Z=\mathbf W\xx, $ $$\mathbf Z= \mathbf I-k\mathbf W. \tag 5$$

If $L^2(k):= \left(\rid-\boldsymbol\beta\right)^\mathsf T \left(\rid-\boldsymbol\beta\right), $ \begin{align}\mathbb E\left[L^2(k)\right]&= \mathbb E\left[\left(\ols-\boldsymbol\beta\right)^\mathsf T \mathbf Z^\mathsf T\mathbf Z\left(\ols-\boldsymbol\beta\right)\right]+ \left(\mathbf Z{\boldsymbol\beta}-\boldsymbol\beta\right)^\mathsf T \left(\mathbf Z{\boldsymbol\beta}-\boldsymbol\beta\right)\\ &= \mathbb E\left[{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}^\mathsf T\mathbf X\left(\xx\right)^{-1}\mathbf Z^\mathsf T\mathbf Z\left(\xx\right)^{-1}\mathbf X^\mathsf T\boldsymbol\varepsilon\right]+ \left(\mathbf Z{\boldsymbol\beta}-\boldsymbol\beta\right)^\mathsf T \left(\mathbf Z{\boldsymbol\beta}-\boldsymbol\beta\right)\\&= \sigma^2\tr\left[\left(\xx\right)^{-1}\mathbf Z^\mathsf T\mathbf Z\right]+   \boldsymbol\beta^\mathsf T\left(\mathbf Z-\mathbf I\right)^\mathsf T \left(\mathbf Z-\mathbf I\right) {\boldsymbol\beta}\\ &\overset{(5)}{=} \sigma^2\left[\tr\mathbf W-k\tr\mathbf W^2\right]+ k^2\boldsymbol\beta^\mathsf T\mathbf W^{2}\boldsymbol\beta\\ &= \underbrace{\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^p \frac{\lambda_i}{(\lambda_i + k)^2}}_{\gamma_1(k) }+ \underbrace{k^2\sum_{i=1}^p \frac{\alpha_i^2}{(\lambda_i + k)^2}}_{\gamma_2(k)};\tag 6
  \end{align}
where $\boldsymbol\alpha = \mathbf P\boldsymbol\beta,~\mathbf P $ being the orthogonal matrix such that $\xx = \mathbf{ P\Lambda P}^\mathsf T, ~\mathbf\Lambda :=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_i).$

**Observation $1.$** $\gamma_1(k) ,$ the variance, is decreasing function of $k$ and $\gamma^\prime_1(k) \to -\infty$ as $k\to +0, ~\lambda_\min\to 0.$

\begin{align}\lim_{k\to +0}\gamma^\prime_1(k)&= \lim_{k\to +0}-2\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{\lambda_i}{(\lambda_i + k)^3} \\ &= -2\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{ 1}{\lambda_i^2}.\tag 7\end{align}

**Observation $2.$** $\gamma_2(k) ,$ the squared bias is increasing function of $k$ and $\gamma^\prime_2(k) \to 0$ as $k\to +0.$

\begin{align}\lim_{k\to +0}\gamma^\prime_2(k)&= \lim_{k\to +0}2k\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{\lambda_i\alpha_i^2}{(\lambda_i + k)^3} \\ &= 0.\tag 8\end{align}

These two observations indicate there are "admissible" values or $k$ for which $\operatorname{MSE}(\rid) $ is lesser than the variance of $\ols.$

**Theorem 1.** (cf. $\rm[IV]$) There exists $k > 0$ such that $\mathbb E\left[L_1^2(k)\right] < \mathbb E\left[L_1^2(0)\right].$

**Proof.** Note $\gamma_1(0)= \sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^p\frac1{\lambda_i}, ~\gamma_2(0) = 0.$

Now, \begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dk}\mathbb E\left[L_1^2(k)\right] 
&= -2\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{\lambda_i}{(\lambda_i + k)^3}+  2k\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{\lambda_i\alpha_i^2}{(\lambda_i + k)^3}; \tag 9\end{align} based on both the observations, it suffices to show that there exists $k>0$ such that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dk}\mathbb E\left[L_1^2(k)\right] <0.$ From $(9), $ the value of $k$ should be $$k < \frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha^2_\max}.\tag{10}$$
$\square$

It must be reiterated again for the sake of gravity, also as mentioned in Sextus Empiricus' [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589150/how-does-ridge-regression-reduce-the-variance-of-the-estimates-of-beta#comment1089000_589198), the agenda is **not** to solely decrease the variance but rather **lower the mean square error of $\rid$ than the variance of the least square estimator $\ols.$** This is done by introducing a little bias and substantially reducing the variance for certain $k>0$ as shown above.

### References:

$[\rm I]$ Algebraic Eigenvalue Problem, *J. H. Wilkinson*, Oxford University Press, $1965.$

$[\rm II]$ Computational Methods of Linear Algebra, *V. N. Faddeeva*, Dover Publications, $1959.$

$\rm[III]$ Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis, *Douglas C. Montgomery, Elizabeth A. Peck, G. Geoffrey Vining*, John Wiley & Sons, $2012.$

$\rm [IV]$  Ridge Regression: Biased Estimation for Nonorthogonal Problems, *Arthur E. Hoerl, Robert W. Kennard*, Technometrics $42,$ no. $1~ (2000): ~80–86. $ https://doi.org/10.2307/1271436.

Comment: Nice post. This proves it very rigorously. I got stuck in my comments with a reasoning that used an eigendecomposition where the eigenvalues are reduced, but I could not convert it into a prove that the variance is reduced let alone the expectation value of the squared error...

Comment: ... one problem with this question is that it is difficult to have the 'helicopter view' of what is happening in the bias variance trade-off. I find the case of estimating the mean of a population much simpler ([Bias / variance tradeoff math](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336433)).

Comment: I do agree. Nevertheless, the paper by Hoerl and Kennard provided a lucid language to show the machinery of the bias variance trade in light of the ridge trace.